# Why both spring-boot-starter-parent and spring-boot-starter-web are needed for Spring Boot application pom?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I am following a video tutorial on Spring Boot (from javabrains.io).  The pom file for the sample project contains a parent block with `groupId` as `org.springframework.boot` and `artifactId` as `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Additionally it contains a dependency block with `groupId` as `org.springframework.boot` and `artifactId` as `spring-boot-starter-web`.

**Q) Why do we need both elements (i.e. parent and dependency) in our pom.xml?**

I thought that since the project pom inherits from `spring-boot-starter-parent`, all the dependencies will be automatically inherited as well.

---

The sample project pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Java Brains Course API</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the the `spring-boot-starter-parent` pom file, you'll see that it provides default properties and maven plugin configuration, whereas `spring-boot-starter-web` provides web-related spring dependencies without any additional configuration. Furthermore, both starters inherit from `spring-boot-dependencies`, which defines a list of dependencies that spring supports. This allows you to omit the version for any of these dependencies in your build configuration. You can learn more by reading [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven).

So to summarize, `spring-boot-starter-parent` provides

- default maven plugin setup
- default maven properties
- dependency management

Whereas `spring-boot-starter-web` pulls in web-related dependencies.